# Diagnosing a Memcache server with a high cache miss rate

Tags: cache, memcache

What tools are available to debug a memcache server with a high miss rate (62%)?

Ideally I would like to know the keys for the top cache misses, but I would just settle for seeing the keys of live get requests and working it out from there.

I have tried a few web based things (phpMemcache) but it doesn't have the information I need. I also tried statsproxy-1.0 which appeared to do what I need but would not play ball.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you build memcached from source
http://code.google.com/p/memcached/downloads/list

there is a memcached-debug version you can run.

Then rather than the usual memcached server you could just do something like:
/usr/local/sbin/memcache-debug -v 9 > /tmp/memcached.log

I think it shows every transaction and result code.

Another way,would be to have just a teensy bit of wrapper code in the application
that logs each put and get and the result.

Comment: I am kind of between a rock and hard place as it is a live server so I can't easily make some wrapper code.